# Schedule notifications for some future date & time in IOS using PhoneGap

Tags: cordova, notifications

i m developing my app in Intel XDk IDE and using local notification plugin(katzer/cordova-plugin-local-notifications) in my app and i want to show notification at some specific time and date when any user want to set notifications at some future date & time on that date & time notification appear, this is my code

```
function reminder(){
var msg = document.getElementById("myText").value;
if(msg==''){
msg='Please Take flower..';
}
var date = document.getElementById("myDate").value;
var time = document.getElementById("myTime").value;
var now = new Date(date+' '+time).getTime(), _60_seconds_from_now=new Date(now+1*1000);
window.plugin.notification.local.add(
{
id: 1,
title: 'title',
message: msg,
repeat: 'daily',
date: _60_seconds_from_now
});
navigator.notification.alert("Successfully Add Notification ",null,"  Notification","OK" );
}

<input type="date" id="myDate">
<input type="time" id="myTime">
<input type="text" id="myText">
<button type="submit" onclick="reminder()" >Reminder</button>
```

But when i click button (Reminder) my app crashes in IOS But the same code works in Android.so if you can please provide any help, I'll be really appreciative.

Thanks

Comment: Please get time delay when add many local notification. That seem issue in IOS 8. App crash because you add many local notification at the same time.

Comment: @Hanh Le Thanks for your response,can you plz give me any example for scheduling notification at some specific time and date and when i alert(now); it show me  the alert(NaN) and then app crashes. can you plz help me why this is happening and how can i solve this problem.

Comment: alert must show with text not "NaN". Please check navigator.notification.alert

Comment: I hope my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47821889/2401386) helps you.